# Transient errors with Sql Azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database

We've got the following DB Configuration setup, however we're still seeing a large volume of transient error notifications when operating against SQL Azure (P1 tier).

```
public class DbConfiguration : System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration
{    public DbConfiguration()
   {
       SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy(5, TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:03"));
   }
}
```

Can anyone familiar with this please comment on anything we may be setting up incorrectly? We are using EF6.

The exact exception we are getting is:

> An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.
>           Exception Full Value:   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>           at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>           at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>           at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>           at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>           at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>           at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>           at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>           at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>           at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>           at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>           at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>           at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>           at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>           at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>           at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
>           at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>           at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass47`1.b__45()
>           at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>           at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>           at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, ObjectParameter[] parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Transient errors occur in Azure due to below reasons(not an elaborate list..)

1.Your database is under heavy load(using up all/reaching dtu quota)

Use below DMV to see DTU metrics

```
SELECT 
    (COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_cpu_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'CPU Fit Percent'
    ,(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_log_write_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Log Write Fit Percent'
    ,(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_data_io_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Physical Data Read Fit Percent'
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
```

2.If you see DTU usage is normal at the time of transient failures,but still seeing errors,it would be good to see if there is a chance of optimization.We used to have same failures,we optimized sql code and did index rebuild and stats

3.reach out to Azure Support with the timestamps of failures to see if there is any maintenance activity

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the ‘SqlAzureExecutionStrategy’ in the entity framework which in turn calls the ‘DbExecutionStrategy’ which has exponential backoff as the inbuilt mechanism. The can lead to greater delays I would recommend the following:
1) Retrying linearly after 5.5sec is ideal. The client caches the error message for 5sec so even if you retry within this time period it will just send you the cached message. 
2) The timeout recommended is 30 sec.
3) Also I would highly recommend connection pooling, the details are here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Also can you please send me the server name and the database name at dmalik@Microsoft.com if possible with the duration of the outages and frequencies?

Answer (score 0):

After research I found that it was related to the limits of Azure SQL Database maximum logins. I was using '**Basic**' service tire and max concurrent users can login with that is 30.

Azure has pricing tiers that have quite dramatic differences in performance. To achieve that, they throttle a lot of performance metrics, e.g. CPU power, requests per minute, etc.

This means that if you're pushing over your tier, your requests will start getting queued up as the CPU power / volume of requests is too high to process. This results in timeouts and then the request limit grows as requests wait to be processed. Eventually, it gets to the point where the database essentially goes down.

My experience is that the lower database levels, such as S0 and S1, are under-powered and shouldn't be used for anything other than development or very basic sites.

There are some great tools in the Azure portal that allow you to debug what is going on with your database, such as the CPU graphs, index advisor and query performance insights.

***Here are the related links: ***

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/latam/2015/06/01/how-to-deal-with-the-limits-of-azure-sql-database-maximum-logins/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits-single-databases

You need to upgrade the subscription in the Azure if that solve your problem. or Enable an execution strategy as mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835.aspx .

Hope this helps !!

Thanks.